# How to create installshield to place dll in windows\system?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, installshield

Can anyone suggest how I should go about creating an installshield in visual studio 2012 which places third party dlls in windows/system32? I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access the System32 folder is to run as an adminastor, because Windows Protects it by default to stop a program, well deleting windows...

You can do the following to make sure the program has admin permissions:

You can edit the UAC Settings (in VB 2008) which is located in the Project Settings. Look for the line that says

Change level="asInvoker" to:

level="asInvoker" (normal account - default)

level="requireAdministrator (require administrator - What you need... but could be next one)

level="highestAvailable" (if anything is higher then administrator, require that)

Hope it helps :)

-nfell2009